# Use External jars in hadoop with hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

How do I access external jars in mapper function while doing mapreduce with hbase in JAVA? I am able to access the objects requiring external jars in the main class but not in the mapper class.

Comment: Please add sample code and details list of libs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(Configuration conf, Class... classes)

Job...
TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job, org.myclass1, org.myclass2);

https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableMapReduceUtil.html#addDependencyJars%28org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.Class...%29

Answer (score 0):

[DistributedCache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) may be helpful, if I understand you correctly.